# Reboot loop after the "effective power" message

Tags: ios, software

If you are not known about this phemomenon, sending this message to someone with iOS will cause the phone to reboot **once**.

However, this time the phone **doesn't stop rebooting**. After the reboot is finished, it starts with a new reboot. Basically I'm stuck.

Is there anything I can do to make this loop stop?

Thanks a lot in advance